# Projecting a N-dimensional Sphere in the positive quadrant onto a n-1 dimensional hyperplane (Simplex) in the positive quadrant

Tags: geometry

I've created an excel interface for users to solve an optimization problem on a set of numbers that satisfy the following equation. I am maximizing a quadratic form subject to the following constraints.

$$ \text{max } a^T Q a   \text{   where   } a = (a_i)  \text{ and  } Q \text{ is positive semi-definite }$$

$$ \text{ such that  } \sum_{i=1}^{n} a_i^2 = 1 $$

along with no-negativity constraints. $$a_1 \geq 0 \forall i$$

In addition to the above constraints, the the user (In the excel tool) can put additional constraints such as $$ a_1 < 0.4 , \text{ or } a_5 = 0.6 $$

Since the users are not math savvy, I have been requested to convert the constraints in the user interface into percentages, something the users and my bosses are more comfortable with. The flavor of the problem is one of allocation of importance and the users prefer to think in terms of percentages.

$$ a_i \longleftrightarrow p_i $$

so something like $$ p_1 < 40\% \text{ or } p_5 = 60\%$$

I think this essentially means I have to have a mapping from a hyperplane  (in the positive quadrant),or simplex is the correct term, to the surface of a sphere in the positive quadrant in my n-dimensional space. So for any constraint space described in terms of percentages, I map it onto the surface of a sphere, solve my optimization, and then map my solution back onto the hyperplane in terms of percentages.In order to pin down this transformation, I am considering connecting points that lie on lines coming out of the origin. At the very least, it works intuitively for the cases where all the weight lies on one dimension or when all the weights are equal.

So a 2D situation will look like this:

[image]

So I guess for a given  set of $$ a_i$$, I get 
$$ p_i =  \frac{a_i}{\sum\limits_{j=1}^{n}a_j }$$

and for a given set of $$p_i$$, I have

$$a_i^2 = \frac{p_i^2}{\sum\limits_{j=1}^{n}p_j^2}$$

I got the above formula by using the property that the points lay on the same line passing through the origin.

But consider the three dimensional case where the user places the constraint that $$p_1 = 80\%$$ This doesn't translate into $$a_1$$ being a fixed point. For example, $$(p_1,p_2,p_3) = (0.8,0.2,0) \longleftrightarrow (a_1,a_2,a_3) = (0.970143,0.242563,0)$$ whereas $$(p_1,p_2,p_3) = (0.8,0.1,0.1) \longleftrightarrow (a_1,a_2,a_3) = (0.984732,0.123091,0.123091)$$

Which I guess is ok?

My question is, am I going about this in a meaningful way?

The above formula translates n-tuples on the simplex to n-tuples on the sphere. So far, I haven't yet worked out the formula for converting the constraint space on the Simplex into a constraint space into the positive quadrant of the n-dimensional sphere. I wanted to get feedback on whether what I am trying is mathematically sound. Any guidance on how to go about working out the formula for mapping constraint spaces would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Your problem is not clear: what are you maximising (or minimising)?

Comment: @Aretino I didn't specify that in the question because it didnt seem relevant. I am simply maximizing a quadratic form. I can edit the question to add that.

Comment: In view of my answer below I think you'd better rephrase your problem in term of percentages from the outset, if that's possible.

Comment: Alternatively, you could try a recursive approach.

Comment: @Aretino How would the recursive approach go?

Comment: You can, at first, set all the unknown $p_i$ to some value (e.g. all equal among them) to compute the bounds on $a_i$. When you have found the solution, use that solution to refine the initial values, computing $\sum p_i^2$ with the solution, and find another (better) solution. Hopefully the process will converge.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can express all $a_i$ as a function of $a_1$:
$$
a_i={p_i\over p_1}a_1.
$$
Plugging that into $\sum_{i=1}^n a_i^2=1$ yields:
$$
a_i={p_i\over\sqrt{\sum_{i=1}^n p_i^2}},
$$
which is the transformation you are looking for.

Unfortunately, you can then map constraints on $p_i$ to constraints on $a_i$ only if you know all values of $p_i$.

Comment: ok so that's exactly the transformation I arrived at and have listed in my question. Hmm... ok.. I guess it's better to simply transform the problem at the outset. That makes sense. ok lemme try that. Thank you!